# Xcode openURL doesn't read link

Tags: objective-c, url, xcode4.2, wikipedia, openurl

I have an animal list and special button. When I press the button, I would like to go to Wikipedia and read about this animal more. So I wrote this code:

```
-(IBAction)goWiki:(id)sender
{
    NSString *wikiUrl = "http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",wikiUrl,animalTitle];  
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}
```

`NSLog` shows that url was written correctly, however, nothing happened. I am 99,9% sure its because of `animalTitle`. My native language is russian and `animalTitle` is also an animal name in russian.
So if link is like *http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog* its fine and it works but if its like
*http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лягушка* nothing happens.
Any ideas, how can I move to a russian article?
Thanks!

Comment: That is not the way to construct a URL. Always start with NSURL and use methods like URLByAppendingPathComponent:. Don't insert slashes manually like that. Don't put "http://" manually either. If you had constructed the URL with `initWithScheme:host:path:`, as you are supposed to do, this problem would probably never have arisen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`  as follows -

```
-(IBAction)goWiki:(id)sender
{
    NSString *wikiUrl = @"http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",wikiUrl,animalTitle];  


    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the string `animalTitle` through CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes first.