# Code not opening page as expected

Tags: objective-c

I have this code below in which I open a link from my app, the commented code works fine and I can open the Wikipedia page. However, I am trying to do a google search instead and using link as a parameter. but the page open blanks. Im really not sure as to why that is happening because if I copy and paste into my browser it opens the google page. Is it because of the formatting?

any help is appreciated.
Thank you

```
  NSString *link=self.goLink;
  NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/search?q=%@",link];

 //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your formatting of your query string.

take a look at this [Xcode openURL doesn't read link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351843/xcode-openurl-doesnt-read-link)